# Combine arrays in Mathematica?

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I have two lists-of-lists which can be schematically summarized by this:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
b = {{4}, {5}, {6}};
```

I want to combine them into a single list of lists, with each element at the same level, ala:

```
    {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}
```

Except I cannot for the life of me make it happen.  The most obvious thing looks like:

```
In[537]:= Append[a, b]
Out[537]= {{1}, {2}, {3}, {{4}, {5}, {6}}}
```

Which isn't what I want.  The Append documentation doesn't seem to cover a case like this, and I can get no amount of Appending and Flattening to work.  I suppose I could write a for loop and just keep adding to an empty list, but good god is that clumsy.  There must be an elegant way to do it?

Comment: Consider cross-posting Mathematica-related questions on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com, which is currently *the* place for Mathematica-related discussions and questions

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I wasn't even aware that there was a Mathematica SE site.

Comment: It is still in beta, but most of the Mathematica regulars don't actually look at the questions here anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
In[537]:= Append[a, b]
```

to:

```
In[537]:= Join[a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the optimal way (the optimal one is mentioned by PinnyM) , but you may consider

```
Flatten[Append[a,b]]
```

or simply

```
Append[a,b]//Flatten
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: Or, without using `Flatten`:  ## & @@@ {a, b}